# Interpolate Effects in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, effects

I have an image in After Effects that is slowly growing. After 5 seconds, I want the image to quickly grow. When I do this however, using 2 transition effects, the 'joint' at which the 2 transition animations connect looks a bit odd, because there is this sudden change in the velocity of the speed it's growing at.

Is there a way to have it interpolate between these 2 effects so it seems like the transition/scaling has a smooth increase in speed?

Comment: Are you simply scaling the image up? Can you add a screen shot of your timeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, do it as one effect and use the graph editor to use a non-linear curve.  You can alter the curve to respond however you'd like then.

[image]

Simply click on the graph looking icon next to your parameter that you are keying on so that it will appear in the graph editor.  Then open the graph editor (icon closest to the timeline on the top (looks like a graph).  Select an option such as Auto Bezier or Auto Ease In or Auto Ease Out as you desire.  Auto Bezier will give you more control over how the curve responds by dragging the bezier anchors (the ones that appear off to the side of the end points.)

Also, don't use a transition effect, use a scale with keyframes.

Comment: yup, I agree, a powerful tool (the visual graph) that allows to add believable motion and scaling to objects. I usually overshoot and wobble/swing my effects before stopping it.